# Is this a form of cadence?

Tags: chords, composition, harmony, cadence

I had to harmonize a piece in E major with a given melody. The image below shows the end of the piece, with my harmonization. [image]
Normally, I would write the first beat of the second-to-last bar as B in the bass, B in the tenor, D# in the alto, and F# in the soprano, i.e. the Vth chord of E major.

But, does it make any sense to write the chord depicted in the image, instead of the standard V chord? Does it have a name? To my ear, it sounds like a cadential 6/4 chord, but I think it's not, since it contains F# and not G#. Can I have this form of cadence, or, is this a way to end the piece?

Thank you in advance, and have a happy New Year!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you wrote is a perfectly good cadence.

I would describe the E simply as an accented passing-note in the alto between the F# and D#. The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonchord_tone#Passing_tone_2) definition is

> A passing tone (PT) or passing note is a nonchord tone prepared by a
>   chord tone a step above or below it and resolved by continuing in the
>   same direction stepwise to the next chord tone (which is either part
>   of the same chord or of the next chord in the harmonic progression).

It does sound a bit like a 6/4 chord - but there is nothing wrong with writing a harmonic progression which creates a sense of ambiguity for the listener, and then resolves it.

Others may want to call it a suspended 4th chord (even though the E isn't a suspension because it isn't the continuation of an E at the end of bar 1) or a dominant 11th. But if you wrote it because it *sounds* right, that's more important than giving it a pedantically correct name!

Whether you are "permitted" to do such a thing if you want full marks in an exam is a different issue, of course. "Passing music exams" and "writing music" are not necessarily the same thing!

As a very minor point, it would be more usual to write the F# in the top part as a single dotted-whole-note, not as you did. Most music notation software should be able to handle three "voices" or "layers" with independent rhythms on one stave.

Comment: I tend to agree - accented passing tone it is. The penultimate bar is really just a decorated dominant seventh. The OP could have easily interpolated a G♯ in the descant above the E to make a second inversion tonic chord, so he is right in that what he has done here is much akin to the second inversion: the skip to a second between the descant and alto is perhaps a bit bolder.

Comment: @Patrx2 "The OP could have easily interpolated a G♯ in the descant above the E" - except that he/she was "harmonizing a given melody", not "composing" ;)

Comment: Yup, but how easily the G♯ can be fitted in shows how closely akin to I 6/4 - V7 - I the OP's writing is here (which was the point I was trying to make). I was essentially confirming OP's suspicions about that.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a note of anticipation in the First beat of that second bar, you are just going about it a little bit wrong. Have your full chord and just go the F sharp on the weak part of the pulse in the manner of a non-chordal note.

Your chord choices are good. You have a Tonic 6/4 going to a Dominant chord with the use of a seventh. Your voice leading just needs to be a little bit better.

This also seems to be a great place to have your Leading Tone note drop by a third. It looks like that will improve the voices tremendously. Remember that in a cadence at the end of a piece the Leading Tone note can drop by a third as long as it features in the Alt or Tenor voices (Not in the outer voices.)

So rather this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Shall we call this an 'unprepared suspension'?  Or an 'accented passing note'?  It gives a satisfing alto line, which is probably more important than vertical analysis.  Plenty in common with a cadential 6/4 indeed.